# Inefficient LINQ - Know What SQL Should Be - Can't get there

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I know the SQL I want to produce:

```
SELECT qdt, pbn, cid, pid, SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM SomeDb.SomeTable
WHERE Status = 'Open'
GROUP BY cid, pid, qdt, pbn
ORDER BY qdt
```

I have LINQ, that I was hoping would produce something as clean as the above SQL:

```
var query = (
  from someTable in SomeTable
  where someTable.Status == "Open"
  group someTable by new { someTable.cid, someTable.pid } into grouped
    select new
    {
      lid = grouped.FirstOrDefault().lid,
      qdt = grouped.FirstOrDefault().qdt,
      pbn = grouped.FirstOrDefault().pbn,
      cid = grouped.FirstOrDefault().cid,
      cn = grouped.FirstOrDefault().cn,
      pid = grouped.FirstOrDefault().pid,
      amount = grouped.Sum(o => o.Amount),
      Status = grouped.FirstOrDefault().Status
});
```

But that produces many lines of nasty SQL. Each grouped value ends up getting its own SELECT statement within the query, like this, for qdt:

```
SELECT [t5].[qdt]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1) [t4].[qdt]
    FROM [SomeDb].[SomeTable] AS [t4]
    WHERE ([t1].[cid] = [t4].[cid]) AND ([t1].[pid] = [t4].[pid]) AND ([t4].[Status] = @p0)
    ) AS [t5]
) AS [qdt]
```

Is there a way to change the LINQ to produce the simpler SQL?

Comment: I have never had good luck with EF / Linq to SQL.  Performance and efficiency are hard to obtain with them.  You might be better off using ADO.NET or a micro ORM like Dapper.

Comment: Yeah, the SQL that EF produces is pretty nasty. I'm considering ADO.NET. Haven't used Dapper before.

Comment: The FirstOrDefault calls are what is ruining your performance.

Comment: @TravisJ What should it be instead?

Comment: It might be faster to pull the set and do the grouping in memory.

Comment: First, your Linq statement isn't grouping on the same fields, but that's a different problem. As for a solution, drop the FirstOrDefaults, use the group's key. (`grouped.Key.[field]`). (Everywhere you're using FirstOrDefault, those fields should likely be in your grouping, and will therefore be part of the group's key.)

Comment: By the way, Linq-to-EF is rarely ever to produce the same SQL you would, and that's OK. The key is just being able to verify that it produces functionally equivalent SQL that gives you the right results and with the right performance.

Comment: The `grouped.Key.Field` only works if the field is in the group list: `by new { someTable.cid, someTable.pid }`. And I guess all those fields should be in the group list anyway.

Comment: That's correct, they should. That is, if your intent is to actually reproduce your original query, as you stated.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Your suggestion is producing the SQL I wanted. If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Someone else is free to cobble that together with code and possible improvements. I'm on mobile at the moment.

Comment: The main problem is that the LINQ statement produces output that the SQL statement can't ever produce. It's apples and oranges. The SQL can only return the 4 grouping fields and the aggregate expression. The LINQ returns 3 more fields from the item that happens to be the first item in the grouping. That's richer output, but at a cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues I see with your LINQ attempt. For starters, you are not grouping by the same fields in the SQL query as in your LINQ. Then, you are using `FirstOrDefault` on the results of the group instead of selecting the group's key data.

Your query should look like this:

```
var query = 
(
    from someTable in SomeTable
    where someTable.Status == "Open"
    group someTable by new 
    { 
        someTable.lid, 
        someTable.qdt,
        someTable.pbn,
        someTable.cid,
        someTable.cn,
        someTable.pid,
        someTable.Status,
    } into grouped
    select new
    {
        lid = grouped.Key.lid,
        qdt = grouped.Key.qdt,
        pbn = grouped.Key.pbn,
        cid = grouped.Key.cid,
        cn = grouped.Key.cn,
        pid = grouped.Key.pid,
        amount = grouped.Sum(o => o.Amount),
        Status = grouped.Key.Status
    }
);
```

I cannot test right now whether it will generate the exact same SQL though.

Comment: It's very likely not producing the same output, unless the added grouping fields happen to be identical within each group of the four original grouping fields. See my comment below the question: the question isn't realistic.

Comment: @GertArnold Yeah, I know the question isn't realistic, but this should be much better in both cleanness and performance.

Comment: Doesn't matter much when it isn't correct though. I guess that's something OP should decide.

Comment: The output should be correct if the exact same grouping fields are used with `grouped.Key.Field`, right?

Comment: Yes, but that only gives you four fields. The other three still need `FirstOrDefault()`. (Well, `Status` could be part of the grouping as well, since you're only querying one `Status`).

Comment: Ok, right. That's at least better. If that saves five `FirstOrDefault()` calls that get converted to worse SQL, then that's improvement.

Comment: This answer gives the blue-print. For a pure match to the original SQL, you eliminate the extra fields from Linq. If the extra fields *are* needed, you accept that there will be a difference and decide if grouping with those is correct or if another approach is needed.

Answer (score -4):

You don't seem to have all the grouped by columns in the desired sql in your linq;

```
var query = (
  from someTable in SomeTable
  where someTable.Status == "Open"
  group someTable by new { someTable.cid, someTable.pid, someTable.qdt,someTable.pbn, someTable.Status } into grouped
    select new
    {
      qdt = grouped.FirstOrDefault().qdt,
      pbn = grouped.FirstOrDefault().pbn,
      cid = grouped.FirstOrDefault().cid,
      pid = grouped.FirstOrDefault().pid,
      Status = grouped.FirstOrDefault().Status,
      amount = grouped.Sum(o => o.Amount)

});
```

I can't really test it but that looks a little more like the sql you are trying to replicate in linq.

Comment: Shouldn't `grouped.FirstOrDefault().cid`be `grouped.Key.cid`? (same with all other fields...)